# Two windows appear on my tkinter app

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.5

I am quite new to python and tkinter and I was trying to open iamges to use them as icons on my program, so I found I have to use tk.Toplevel instead of tk.Tk. However, when I do this, the application opens two windows,the one where everything is programmed and a blank one.

Here is the full code in case anyone could help:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import PhotoImage
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

Large_Font = ("Times", 20)

class RobProject(tk.Toplevel):

    def __init__(self):

        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self)

        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Com-Bot Control")

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (MenuPage, PageOne, PageTwo, PageThree):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="NEWS")

        self.show_frame(MenuPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class MenuPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

        label = tk.Label(self, text = "Menú", font=Large_Font)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        RCB = ttk.Button(self, text="Control Remoto",
                        command= lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        RCB.pack()

        EOB = ttk.Button(self, text="EvitaObstáculos",
                        command= lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
        EOB.pack()

        SLB = ttk.Button(self, text="Siguelíneas",
                        command= lambda: controller.show_frame(PageThree))
        SLB.pack()

        img = Image.open("play-button.png")
        photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

        Show_Im = tk.Button(self, image=photo)
        Show_Im.image = photo
        Show_Im.pack()

class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        label = tk.Label(self, text = "Control Remoto", font=Large_Font)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        Back_B1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Atrás",
                        command= lambda: controller.show_frame(MenuPage))
        Back_B1.pack()

class PageTwo(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        label = tk.Label(self, text = "Evitaobstáculos", font=Large_Font)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        Back_B2 = ttk.Button(self, text="Atrás",
                        command= lambda: controller.show_frame(MenuPage))
        Back_B2.pack()        

class PageThree(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        label = tk.Label(self, text = "Siguelíneas", font=Large_Font)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        Back_B3 = ttk.Button(self, text="Atrás",
                        command= lambda: controller.show_frame(MenuPage))
        Back_B3.pack()

app = RobProject()
app.mainloop()
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You need `tk.Tk()` to start the tkinter application. `tk.Toplevel()` is for opening new windows in general not something you would use to start the application up.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need `Topelevel()` to use images.
Not sure where you got that info but it is not accurate.

`Toplevel()` is specifically to create new windows outside of the root window in tkinter.

What is happening is when you call `tk.Toplevel()` tkinter is creating an instance of `Tk()` in order to run `Toplevel()`. This is where the blank screen is coming from. The blank screen is actually the root window without anything in it.

To fix your problem Change:

```
class RobProject(tk.Toplevel):

    def __init__(self):

        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self)
```

To:

```
class RobProject(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
```

Comment: I had to do it because otherwise I had an error that tells me something like pyimageN does not exist.
However, now changing it it does not appear any more, i have no idea why... But it worked, so thank you!

Comment: @SergioLatorreMuñoz most likely the problem was with your image path. Either the path had a typo or the image was not in the path specified.